# Submiting a form to the destination of a side-bar menu link (javascript / php / html form)

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a multi page form, navigable both by forward and back buttons, but also via a side bar menu.

I want to avoid data that has been entered on the current page being lost, if the user leaves the page via the sidebar menu navigation:

**Desired Goal:**

When a user clicks the link in a menu, the "action" attribute of the form, is adjusted to match the destination of that link. As there are several pages, I'd rather not hard code several "if link to page1.php is click, then make the action equal page1.php etc", so much as a function that can be called on click of a link, and will set the action to whatever the link destination is.

**My attempt:**

(I'm learning JavaScript, so I really am stabbing about in the dark a bit, I'd like to understand `this` better)

Here is my html

```
<form id="myform" action="default_action.php" method="POST">

... form inputs...

<input type="submit" name="DefaultSubmit" value="Next Page">
</form>


<div id="navmenu" class="navmenu">
    <ul id="sidebarmenu1">
        <li><a href="?page=1" class="menu1" onclick="OnMenuClick()">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=2" class="menu2" onclick="OnMenuClick()">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=3" class="menu3" onclick="OnMenuClick()">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my attempt at javascript:

```
<script>
function OnMenuClick()
{
document.myform.action ="this.getAttribute("href")"
document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

I stitched it together from reading various tutorials, but it seems like there are many ways to do one thing, and so far this isn't working for me, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to include jQuery on your site (and hey, everyone's doing it :) ), I would suggest the following:

```
<form id="myform" action="default_action.php" method="POST">

... form inputs...

<input type="submit" name="DefaultSubmit" value="Next Page">
</form>
<div id="navmenu" class="navmenu">
    <ul id="sidebarmenu1">
        <li><a href="?page=1" class="menu1">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=2" class="menu2">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=3" class="menu3">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#sidebarmenu1 a').on('click', function (event) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#myform').attr('action', url);
        $("#myform").submit();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});​
```

If you're just getting into javascript, jQuery is a great place to get started and you can include it on your site just by adding to following to your `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is no need to use jQuery here.

Comment: I already use jQuery throughout my site actually, for other things (not that I understand much about it yet! So this looks like it would work.. let me just try and incorporate it into my real code... thanks!

Comment: I know, but I figured if someone is just learning javascript, they'll be far less frustrated with browser differences and all the other headaches library-less javascript brings along. There's always more than one answer :)

Comment: no problem - If you've already got jquery, you might as well use it :) - although make sure you're using 1.7 or later else .on() won't work

Comment: Yes I think I have the latest one (installed it the other day). I've added in your script, but it's not working so far... does it matter that the menu is outside of the `form`? Is it correct that it should be loading on DOM load? (That's what the encapsulation does, correct?)

Comment: To test this, I inspected the form element, and adjusted the script to fire `.on('hover', ...` to see if it was working, and it is not adjusting the action of the form. Anything I could be doing wrong.

Comment: looks like i capitalized the F in form in the selector by accident. Here's a working version on JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nmartin413/VJqts/1/

Comment: Also, you'll have to remove the `onclick="blah"` stuff

Comment: Great! Actually my real form has another name, so I'd substituted it, but the function began working when I moved it up above my other javascript (weird... right, because on DOM load, order shouldn't matter?!) anyway, it's working now, and I am honoured to give you your first accepted answer! :D Thanks so much

Comment: Glad to hear its working & thanks for the acceptance! You're right in the fact that `$(function () {` is just short for `$(document).ready(`. If you're mixing normal javascript and jquery style stuff I'd try to avoid that, or at least wrap the normal javascript in a `$(function () {` as well :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20297/discussion-between-gideon-and-nmartin413)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div id="navmenu" class="navmenu">
    <ul id="sidebarmenu1">
        <li><a href="?page=1" class="menu1" onclick="OnMenuClick(this)">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=2" class="menu2" onclick="OnMenuClick(this)">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=3" class="menu3" onclick="OnMenuClick(this)">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
function OnMenuClick(element)
{
    document.myform.action = element.getAttribute("href");
    document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should world:

```
<div id="navmenu" class="navmenu">
    <ul id="sidebarmenu1">
        <li><a href="?page=1" class="menu1" onclick="OnMenuClick(this)">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=2" class="menu2" onclick="OnMenuClick(this)">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=3" class="menu3" onclick="OnMenuClick(this)">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    function OnMenuClick(t)
    {
      document.getElementById('myform').action =t.getAttribute("href")
      document.myform.submit();
    }  
</script>
```